# Put MailChimp input and subscribe button on same line

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I'm looking to get this email subscribe form from MailChimp to appear all on one single horizontal line. Here is how it appears now:

[image: Current version]

I'd like for the wording to display how it currently is, and have the input field for email and the Subscribe button all on the same line.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#546C7C; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;  width:300px; color: #fff;}
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//Gaylebrickman.us15.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=48a6b6c222ef150a6559c63df&amp;id=bf44114a3d" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">For Mindfulness Events and Tips</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_48a6b6c222ef150a6559c63df_bf44114a3d" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Comment: try removing the div with class as clear and see if it fixes it. I have a feeling the clear is putting it in a new line. If it doesnt let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to shift `<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">` to below `<label for="mce-EMAIL">For Mindfulness Events and Tips</label>`.

And then you have to add this anywhere in the code:

```
<style>
    #mc_embed_signup_scroll {display: inline}
</style>
```

Comment: Else everything remains the same. If there is still an error, let me know

Comment: `block inline` is not valid CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following CSS to your `<style>` tag:

```
#mc_embed_signup input.email,
#mc_embed_signup input.button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The external stylesheet sets the `display` property to `block` for both of these elements, so this will override it and put them on the same line.